# Is it possible to configure Nginx to send TCP keepalive?

Tags: nginx, tcpip

On TCP connections held by NGinx, can it be configured to send [TCP Keepalive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html)

(**Not** HTTP KeepAlive!)

Comment: Use the source, Luke. (but **why** would you want to do such a thing?)

Comment: So our firewall would not disconnect long lived connections.

Comment: Why don't you just tell your firewall not to terminate long connections?

Comment: Because there might be other firewalls along the way - I don't control them all.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to use so_keepalive in the http listen directive ? or did you go other way ?

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options:

- use stock `so_keepalive` nginx option
- use `nginx-tcp-keepalive` module directives

## listen ... so_keepalive=on

`listen` directive with `so_keepalive` option is `server` level. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen for full documentation. This option is available since 2011-12-12 in nginx 1.1.11 and later.

## tcp_keepalive=on

The [nginx-tcp-keepalive](https://github.com/nviennot/nginx-tcp-keepalive) module of [Nicolas Viennot](https://serverfault.com/a/334953/7005) provides family of `tcp_keep*` directives that are `location` level. This module should work properly on modern Linux and BSD systems. Mac OS X support is limited to `tcp_keepalive` only. The module was originally releases approximately in the moment when nginx gained the `so_keepalive` option. I hadn't tried if the module is still compatible with newer version of nginx.

Answer (score 3):

Made it: https://github.com/nviennot/nginx-tcp-keepalive

Comment: does the existing listen option: `so_keepalive` not work?

Comment: As far as I see the `so_keepalive` is on per server basis since it is option to `location` directive. The module allows that configuration per location basis, that can be significant difference in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, only mail proxy module supports "so_keepalive" directive.

Answer (score 1):

[There is as LD_PRELOAD module that turns keepalives on](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#libkeepalive), even if the app doesn't have an option to do so.
(I don't know if it works with nginx or not.)